# MySQL Select, column with same name from multiple tables, order by another column with same name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select rows with a certain column name and order them by another column name.

Here's my problem, into N simplified tables:

`table 1: id, username, datetime, comment`

`table 2: id, username, datetime, vote`

.

.

.

`table N: id, username, datetime, bought`

I want to be able to select all rows where `username='Some Name'`, ordered by datetime -- across all N tables.

--

Incidentally, does anyone know of a good book or resource on learning and practicing advanced SQL? (Tried SQLZoo, but they don't have enough advance examples.. and then there are the too-advanced ones that I'm still stumped on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking to sort across ALL the tables at the same time (a newer record from table 3 shows up before something from table 2, etc)

The easiest way to do this across multiple tables would be a UNION:

```
(SELECT id, username, datetime FROM table 1 WHERE username = 'Some Name')
UNION 
(SELECT id, username, datetime FROM table 2 WHERE username = 'Some Name')
UNION
(SELECT id, somethingelse AS username, date as datetime FROM table 3 WHERE somethingelse = 'Some Name')
....
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Note that when you use a union like this, all of your select statements should return the same number of columns and be named the same (you can use aliases for this as I showed above in table 3)

Comment: the other two folks suggest alias as a possibility, too (although i am not sure how they are ordering *everything* by datetime ... if both are possible, is alias vs union better in terms of resources?

Comment: If you're looking to order across multiple tables that do not have direct relations, UNIONs are the way to go - that said, this is not especially good for resources since you're making a bunch of subqueries and is usually a sign that you need to change your database schema.  

Also note that if you want to do something like get the 5 newest records, you'll need to set a LIMIT 5 in EACH of the subqueries and then limit on the outer query as well.

Comment: ok, the solution might be just to create an overall dump_transactions table that concatenates everything

Answer (score 2):

Alias your tables in the query, ie.

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.username, ... FROM table1 as t1
```

Comment: problem is how do you order everything by datetime?

Comment: do you want to sort across all tables?

Comment: yup, that's the problem, sorting across all N tables.

Comment: think you should be able to order them like this: 
ORDER BY t1.datetime, t2.datetime, t3.datetime (EDIT: obviously that is not what you want - you will probably have to go with unions as others have suggested).

Answer (score 1):

You can select same column names from different tables like:

```
SELECT table1.username as t1user, table2.username as t2user...
```

Comment: problem is how do you order *everything* by datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNIONS

Select must be somthing like this:

```
(SELECT comment, date FROM table1 WHERE username='Some Name')
UNION
(SELECT vote, date FROM table2 WHERE username='Some Name')
...
UNION
(SELECT bought, date FROM tableN WHERE username='Some Name')
ORDER BY date LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 display_error($this->entity);
        $result = get_leave_status($this->entity);

        start_table(TABLESTYLE, "width=60%");

        $th = array(_("#"),
           _("Login Date"),
            _("Login Time"),
            _("Reason"),
            _("Status"),
            _(" "),

        );

        table_header($th);
           $sl=1;
            while($sl<13){

        display_error($sl);
        $str = ($sl < 10) ? 0 . $sl : $sl;
        $sql="SELECT login_time,login_date,early_leave_reason FROM ".TB_PREF."hcm_attendance_".$str." WHERE emp_code=".  db_escape($this->entity);

        $sl++;
    $result = db_query($sql, "Can't make query in loan_req table.");



        $k = 0;
        $i = 1;
        while ($myrow = db_fetch($result)) {
            alt_table_row_color($k);

            label_cell($i,'align=center');
            label_cell(sql2date($myrow["login_date"]),'align=center');
            label_cell($myrow["login_time"],'align=center');



            label_cell($myrow["early_leave_reason"], "Width=30%");

            if ($myrow["status"] == 1)
                label_cell('Approved');
            elseif ($myrow["status"] == 2)
                label_cell('Rejected');
            else {
                label_cell(viewer_link('Pending',"payroll/inquiry/leave_document.php?eno=".$this->vendor_no.'&lid='.$myrow['id']));

                edit_button_cell("{$this->name}Edit[{$myrow['id']}]", _("EDIT"));
            }
            end_row();
            $i++;
        }

            }
        end_table(1);

here i have used $sl to increment table name like 0_hcm_attendance_01,0_hcm_attendance_02 -------to 0_hcm_attendance_12

here TB_PREF=0;

TB_PREF."hcm_attendance_".$str
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation about your answer will clarify further your point of view.